# Customizer for mergeWith to not merge nested arrays

Tags: nested, lodash

I need to write a customizer for mergeWith. I've used defaultsDeep before and it worked exactly the way I want it to, except that defaultsDeep also merge nested arrays. I have 2 objects.

```
const baseObject = { 
 firstElement: { data: undefined },
 secondElement: {  
  name: 'Canada', 
  items: [ 
  { city: 'Toronto', code: 12334},
  { city: 'Vancouver ', code: 33245}
  ] 
 }
};
const defaultObject = {
 firstElement: { data: '13.01.2018'}, 
 secondElement: { 
  name: 'Bresil', 
  items: [
   { city: 'Rio', code: 67584},
   { city: 'Manaus ', code: 90845}, 
   { city: 'Salvador ', code: 36745}
  ] 
 }
};
```

and when I do `defaultsDeep(baseObject, defaultObject)`
I get:

```
{ 
  firstElement: { data: '13.01.2018' }, 
  secondElement: { 
   name: 'Canada', 
   items: [ 
    {city: 'Toronto', code: 12334},
    {city: 'Vancouver ', code: 33245},
    {city: 'Salvador ', code: 36745}] 
 }
};
```

with mergeWith(`mergeWith(baseObject, defaultObject, (ObjValue) => ObjValue)`)
I get:

```
{ 
  firstElement: { data: undefined }, 
  secondElement: { 
   name: 'Canada',
   items: [ 
    {city: 'Toronto', code: 12334},
    {city: 'Vancouver ', code: 33245}] 
 }
};
```

Please help me to write customizer for mergeWith, I would be very appreciated

I expect :

```
{ 
  firstElement: { data: '13.01.2018' }, 
  secondElement: { 
   name: 'Canada',
   items: [ 
    {city: 'Toronto', code: 12334},
    {city: 'Vancouver ', code: 33245}] 
  }
}
```

I found some resolving, and I understand that some lines no have sens, but it's work somehow :

```
const customizer = (objValue, key) => {
  
  if (isArray(key) || objValue?.subItems) return objValue;
  
  if (key) return;
  
    return objValue;
 };
```

Comment: I found some resolving, and I understand that some line no have sens, but it's work somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customizer function of `_.mergeWith()` should return the value that you want or `undefined`, if you would like `_.mergeWith()` continue merging nested objects:

```js
const { isArray, isObject, isUndefined, mergeWith } = _;

const customizer = (a, b) => {
  if(isArray(a)) return a;
  
  return isObject(a) || isUndefined(a) ? undefined : a;
}

const baseObject = {"firstElement":{},"secondElement":{"name":"Canada","items":[{"city":"Toronto","code":12334},{"city":"Vancouver ","code":33245}]}};
const defaultObject = {"firstElement":{"data":"13.01.2018"},"secondElement":{"name":"Bresil","items":[{"city":"Rio","code":67584},{"city":"Manaus ","code":90845},{"city":"Salvador ","code":36745}]}};

const result = mergeWith(baseObject, defaultObject, customizer);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```